# List of all accounts sorted by balance

Tags: api

Since tzscan.io is offline, I can't find a public API which returns a list of all accounts sorted by balance descending (total amount of tez) eg. whales. I can't find this in tzstats, tezblock nor tezos.id. Is there an API endpoint which returns this information? If yes, where?

Answer (score 1):

You can export a .csv file from the arronax block explorer: https://arronax-beta.cryptonomic.tech/

You can also pull the data directly from the API: https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Conseil

Comment: The downloaded .csv file seems to be incomplete. For example: A few of my wallets don't show up in the file. (I removed all the filters and then hit Share » Export CSV)